# Why doesn't mutable.IndexedSeqLike extend mutable.SeqLike?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

As far as I can see, no declaration clashes would occur if `mutable.IndexedSeqLike` extended `mutable.SeqLike`. Is the lack of inheritance an artifact of incremental design, or an actual decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the former, at [this change](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/2816f2e6ce51206b3b5bdb1367203bf688625cb6#diff-918e4f1e3417b49efc7ca01e5d37d12c) when `Vector` became `IndexedSeq`.

`SeqLike` was created [subsequently](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/deaf94e5f2bcbd719c1b80dfba2aaf16eaa9f75e) to patch [an oversight](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3590).

It happens that `IndexedSeqLike` has fewer abstract methods than `SeqLike` because iteration is defined in terms of indexing. So there's no motivation for extending it.

The `SeqLike.transform` method was added [with a bunch of unrelated changes](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/fee124a41964623dc902464bcbefecd130861eb3), so that wouldn't necessarily drive unifying the interfaces.

The `*Like` traits are implementation templates, merely. `collection.IndexedSeqLike` does inherit behavior from `collection.SeqLike`.

One reason not to extend a trait unnecessarily is that it could change linearization order, even if all actual concrete implementations do mix in the traits.